# Downloading resources e.g images , wav files on user request

Tags: android

Assuming that an application supports several languages and initially supports only English. Then after downloading and installing the APK one user selects somehow "Sweedish" language and then someone else clicks on "French". I would like for my app to download and use spesific resources (lets say large images or wav files that are related to that language ) for that language . Lets assume that the files are quite large and The Portugal user does not need the Spanish resources and vice versa.

Any tips , pointers , url links on how to do that ?

Comment: This is not possible with the Android resource system. You are certainly welcome to download additional files, but you are going to need to treat them as files, not as resources.

Comment: design your app with specific condtions based on selected language...
if i am correct

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with Android resourses.

However, you can do it in other way.

You can upload files that you need on your server.

Then, when user runs your app, you can get the current language

```
Locale.getDefault().getDisplayLanguage();
```

Then, send request to your server and download files that you need for the current language.

Hope, it'll help you.